# Jquery checkbox filtering with mutiple data attributes

Tags: jquery, filtering

I have three sets of checkboxes which allow me to filter a number of divs based on data attributes. On their own they work fine, but when used together it all becomes a bit 'buggy'.

If you visit the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJUb3/) below, and select 'red' from the first filter set, then 'large' from the second filter set, it should display 'Stench Blossom', but it doesn't, it displays nothing. It seems that unless the filtered terms are together in the data attribute, it doesn't work.

How would I go about fixing this issue please? (I hope this makes sense).

Below is the jquery I'm using:

```
            $('.flowers-wrap, .planets-wrap').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
                var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
                    $checked = $('input:checked');  
                if ($checked.length)
                {
                    var selector = $checked.map(function ()
                    {
                        return '' + $(this).attr('id');
                    }).get().join(' ');     
                    $lis.hide();
                    $('.flowers > div').filter('[data-category~="' + selector + '"]').show();           
                    console.log(selector);    
                }
                else
                {
                    $lis.show();
                }
            });
```

Please see the jsfiddle I have setup to demonstrate the issue I'm having - http://jsfiddle.net/nJUb3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem itself lies in the concept of the jQuery selector you're using. The `[attribute~="value"]` matches literally the string you put into it.

For example,

If you select `$("[data-category~='red']")` it'll match the data categories with the "red" word

If you select `$("[data-category~='red large']")` jQuery will literally try to match the "red large" string into the data-category attribute, since your data category has no such string delimited by white spaces, the filter will fail.

To achieve what you're looking for, you need to combine multiple attribute selectors, for more information read this http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

I updated your fiddle based on this concept http://jsfiddle.net/nJUb3/1/ I think this is what you're looking for :)