# Jquery checkbox filtering with mutiple data attributes part 2

Tags: jquery, filtering

Following on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049176/jquery-checkbox-filtering-with-mutiple-data-attributes) I posted; I have three sets of checkboxes which allow me to filter a number of divs based on data attributes. This works great but I need to modify it slightly.

If you visit the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJUb3/1/) below, and select 'earth' from the 'available planets' filter set, then 'red' and 'yellow' from the first filter set, then 'small' from the second filter set, I would like it to display both 'Daisy' and 'Rose', but it doesn't, it displays nothing.

Basically, if any of the inputs from the first or second filter sets are selected, it should display all of the relevant items, but if any inputs from the third filter set are selected, it should only show the filtered items from this set.

How would I go about fixing/amending this issue please? (I hope this makes sense).

Below is the jquery I'm using:

```
            $('.flowers-wrap,.planets-wrap').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
                var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
                    $checked = $('input:checked');  
                if ($checked.length)
                {                           
                    var selector = '';
                    $($checked).each(function(index, element){                            
                        selector += "[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";                            
                    });                        
                    $lis.hide();                        
                    $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).show();               
                }
                else
                {
                    $lis.show();
                }
            });
```

Please see the jsfiddle I have setup to demonstrate the issue I'm having - http://jsfiddle.net/nJUb3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
        $('.flowers-wrap,.planets-wrap').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
            var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
                $checked = $('input:checked');  
            if ($checked.length)
            {                           
                var selector = '';
      $($checked).each(function(index, element){
                  if(selector === '')
                    {
                        selector += "[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";                  
                    }else
                    {
                        selector += ",[data-category~='" + element.id + "']";
                    }
                    });                        
                    $lis.hide(); 
                    alert(selector);
                    $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).show();               
                }
                else
                {
                    $lis.show();
                }
            });
```

you can see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zMyD3/) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zMyD3/)

Comment: thanks for the answer; not quite was I was after but it helps :)